# UPSERT with python-arango driver for ArangoDB

Tags: python-3.x, arangodb, python-arango

I'm using [python-arango](http://python-driver-for-arangodb.readthedocs.io) as a driver for ArangoDB, and there doesn't seem to be an `UPSERT` interface.

*I intended to tag this with* **python-arango**, *but I have insufficient rep to create new tags*.

I'm managing with something like the function shown below, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?

```
def upsert_document(collection, document, get_existing=False):
    """Upserts given document to a collection. Assumes the _key field is already set in the document dictionary."""
    try:
        # Add insert_time to document
        document.update(insert_time=datetime.now().timestamp())
        id_rev_key = collection.insert(document)
        return document if get_existing else id_rev_key
    except db_exception.DocumentInsertError as e:
        if e.error_code == 1210:
            # Key already exists in collection
            id_rev_key = collection.update(document)
            return collection.get(document.get('_key')) if get_existing else id_rev_key
    logging.error('Could not save document {}/{}'.format(collection.name, document.get('_key')))
```

**Note** that in my case I ensure that all documents have a value for `_key` and before insertion, so therefore I can assume that this holds. If someone else wants to use this, modify accordingly.

**EDIT**: Removed use of `_id` field as this is not essential to the issue.

Comment: FWIW, the id is always `{collection}/{_key}`, so you should only have to set the `_key`. The only other way I know is to use AQL and use upsert in the query: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Operations/Upsert.html

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewGrothe, that's a good point. I use the `_id` value in logic between my models before upserting, and thought I should point it out in case someone naively tried to implement a copy of my function. (In the example above it's only used to log errors, so I guess I could've omitted it in the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point in using `upsert` is to save a database roundtrip from the application, which is wy the `try/except` approach isn't as good.

However, at the time being [the ArangoDB HTTP-API](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/HTTP) doesn't offer upserts, thus python-arango can't offer you an API for it.

You should instead use an [AQL query to upsert your document](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/AQL/DataQueries.html#using-old-and-new-in-the-same-query) to achieve this:

```
UPSERT { name: "test" }
    INSERT { name: "test" }
    UPDATE { } IN users
LET opType = IS_NULL(OLD) ? "insert" : "update"
RETURN { _key: NEW._key, type: opType }
```

via [python-arango s `db.aql.execute`-interface](https://python-driver-for-arangodb.readthedocs.io/en/master/aql.html#aql-queries)

Comment: Thanks for adding the good explanation for why `try/except` is not a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `python-arango` you should just be able to do the following:

```
collection.insert({'_key': xxx, ...}, overwrite_mode='replace')
```

or

```
collection.insert({'_key': xxx, ...}, overwrite_mode='update')
```

```
 :param overwrite_mode: Overwrite behavior used when the document key
            exists already. Allowed values are "replace" (replace-insert) or
            "update" (update-insert). Implicitly sets the value of parameter
            **overwrite**.
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this option. I don't think the `overwrite_mode` option was available at the time of the OP, but very useful to know!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use something like this?

```
try:
    collection.update({'_key': xxx, ...})
except db_exception.DocumentInsertError as e:
    document.insert({'_key': xxx, ...})
```